# Understanding lightswitch deployment

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-lightswitch

I wish to deploy a lightswitch application for a small company. I want a central server hosting the database and then the silverlight client to run inside the network connecting to the server and updating the database with clients, etc.

I have made a working system using the intrinsic database in VS2013, but now I come to deploy it and am having problems, despite hours reading MSDN and following tutorials.

I create a deployment package on my development machine, which I then install on the server, but I then need to create a client only package, which points to the server? Does this mean I need to specify the central database as an external data source? Or does this switch happen automatically? Can I publish only the server, and install that on the server machine, (I have already installed the web server package) then publish a separate client package for installing the application on the clients? I need all the clients to update a single database, not all have their own local copies and local databases...

Comment: The problem I was having was I couldn't connect to the deployment server as it was in a different VLAN, which made the auto-complete not work.
I now understand that the 2 tier deployment means that the application sits on the client, with the lightswitch middleware too, and the data is kept in an SQL database all the clients point to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "create a client only package" the intrinsic database is running on the client, so nothing point to the server. 
A external data source is always external regardless of the app type.

What type of a LightSwitch Application you've selected?

- A 2-tier desktop application runs on an end-user Windows desktop. The
  database and server components are deployed to the end-user computer.
- A 3-tier desktop application runs on an end-user Windows desktop. The
  database and server components are deployed to an Internet
  Information Services (IIS) server or to Windows Azure.
- A 3-tier Web    application runs in an end-user web browser. The
  database and server    components are deployed to an Internet
  Information Services (IIS)    server or to Windows Azure.